# Getting man path through Vim

Tags: vim, environment-variables, vimrc, manpages

So, I've set up Vim as my default man viewer. I also have NERDTree starting up automatically - but I could really do without NERDTree showing the location the man pages every time I check man.

I've tried setting up the following in my .vimrc:

```
if (match(expand("%:p:h"),???) == -1)
    " load NERDTree here
endif
```

But I'm not really sure what to match the path against. $MANPATH would be the obvious choice, however `echo $MANPATH` doesn't print anything out in terminal. Running `manpath` does produce `/usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man`, but I have no idea how to include that in my vimrc. Of course I could just paste the paths as a string, but that would be cheating.

Basically, what I'm looking for is either:

- a way to set the $MANPATH variable so that it points to the folders listed by `manpath`
- any other way to get the paths in Vim

EDIT: A post-acceptance note in case anyone wants to try that script - `match` needs to be replaced with `matchstr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let $MANPATH = substitute(system("manpath"), "\n", "", "")
```

The substitute() function removes the trailing newline that the output of system() includes.